# Нахождение остатка от деления больших чисел

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Решал задачу с применением треугольника Паскаля. Из-за быстрого увеличения значений сумма двух предыдущих представляется как остаток по модулю **1e9+7**. Задачу я решил, но вот в ограничение по времени не уложился. тогда мне подсказали, что нужно использовать **малую теорему Ферма**. Вопрос такой: как использовать данную теорему для быстрого вычисления **остатков?**. За примеры кода буду особенно благодарен.

Comment: Используется следствие, что в поле Z_p выполняется равенство a^(-1)=a^(p-2), что позволяет выполнять деление путем умножения... Так что можно быстро вычислить нужное значение по формуле сочетаний, а не путем сложений.

Comment: Тогда не подскажите, каким образом разобраться с факториалами? В задаче могут встречаться числа вплоть до 1e6, и я не знаю таких алгоритмов для их подсчета, которые позволят уложиться в ограничение. Формула Стирлинга, очевидно, не подойдет

Comment: Ну так задайте точный вопрос, а пока это обсуждение теоретических предпосылок. Я ответил... Ответ на ваш вопрос — C_n^m = n!/(m!(n-m)!); ее можно немного подсократить. И еще, когда пишете кому-то, то для того, чтобы этот кто-то получил уведомление, напишите в тексте @ с его именем, типа @Harry :)

Comment: @Harry спасибо за наводку, задачку я решил. И за замечание тоже)